# Detect if player clicks with item such as stick or blaze rod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

how would I detect if player clicks with item such as stick or blaze rod?

I suppose this would use scoreboards?

I also can not use comparators or such, it will all be hooked up to a clock, although there can be commands which are only commenced once at the beginning.

the reason I cant use comparators is because I am creating a one command creation in a generator.

so far I have stared at a wall and tried to think of something.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to use comparators in your system that checks for the item?

Comment: Why can you not use comparators? What have you tried doing thus far?

Comment: Do you want to detect a right click or a left click?

Answer (score 2):

You can do right click and left click detection, luckily, and 1.9 makes this easier than ever!

Prerequisites:

```
/scoreboard objectives add rClick stat.talkedToVillager
/scoreboard objectives add holdingBlazeRod dummy
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"ClickNpc",ActiveEffects:[{id:14b,Duration:10000,Amplifier:0}],Silent:1b,Offers:{}}
```

Put this in a clock:

```
/tp @e[type=Villager,name=ClickNpc] @p
/scoreboard players set @a holdingBlazeRod 0
/scoreboad players set @a holdingBlazeRod 1 {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:blaze_rod}}
```

Type this in front of the command you want to execute when blaze rod is right clicked:

```
/execute @a[score_holdingBlazeRod_min=1,score_rClick_min=1] ~ ~ ~ ...
```

Done!

Comment: Im surprised that this question hasnt gotten the "answer" certification from the question admin.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could get would be the useItem statistic, but this only works for items that have a valid "use" action such as tools, weapons, placeable items/blocks, etc. Scoreboards is not currently possible for items without a "use" action (would be really nice for Mojang to add this in the future). A possible alternative (assuming the right click action is supposed to be a "1-time-use" action and not a continuous action would be to drop a named item on the ground and use the execute command (or similar) to check for a specific item type with a specific name.

Comment: This, however, wouldn't work with sticks and blaze rods, as they can't be "used". And items that *can* be used  (like blocks) would still be used (such as right-clicking with a dirt block; it will still place). The only "true" functionality with useItem is with fishing rods and carrots-on-a-stick.

Answer (score 0):

You could get selected item by using a command like this with a command-block and a comparator :

`/testfor @p {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}`

And then you could use a right-click detector. See this video :

Comment: Can you explain what they do on the video? As the video can be removed, we require answers to explain what they contain.

Comment: Link to video is dead